# Placing UML diagrams in a monorepo

Tags: javascript, architecture, uml, monorepo

A monorepo is a software development strategy where code for many projects is stored in the same repository. This software engineering practice dates back to at least the early 2000s, when it was known as a 'shared codebase'...

Today, I have had the idea of placing my UML diagrams at the root of my monorepo, or inside the documentation workspace/package. Is there any generic (by convention) folder name for this kind of stuff (diagrams/assets/dratf/uml...)? Isn't it a good practice to place UML diagrams of an architecture on the codebase?

Comment: Having just diagrams is the bottom level. You will need the model which can be XMI (but model exchange between tools is less than sub-optimal). Just so: it depends.